# How can I use several point cloud library source files with CMAKE in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm working on a project "**Robotic 3D registration**" that using UR5 robot and 3D scanner on the robot's hand in order to **get multi-view point clouds** of the unknown objects and **reconstruct it with ICP registration**.

I'm trying to make visual studio project and here's my environment

**Cmake 3.8.0-rc1**

**Visual studio 2013**

**point cloud library 1.8.0**

**Windows 10**

I have **completed installing and compiling pcl using source code** with the help of
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0adzJy4-KZg&t=3s

And I have completed several tutorials of pcl following
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/

But these tutorials only use **one source file(.cpp) and one executable**..

For the my project, **I have to build with several source files and this is the question.**

I want to make project with the source files in pcl as below.

xyz2pcd.cpp (for conversion of point cloud data type)

statistical_removal.cpp (for elimination of outliers)

moment_of_inertia.cpp (for generation of AABB or OBB)

pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp (for registration of multi-view point clouds)

robot_control.cpp (for communication and control of the robot)

sensor_control.cpp (for communication and control of the sensor)

and the main executable source file such as main.cpp

As I studied, I think except the main.cpp, all source files should be build as library with add_library command in CMakeLists so that I can use the functions in source file in . Also, in main.cpp, I want to make multiple thread to control ,  and  separately.

So, I made CMakeLists like this..

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

# creat project
project(Project)

# find package
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

set(SYS_NAME project_test)
set(LIB_NAME "pcl_${SYS_NAME}")

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(srcs
     src/tools/xyz2pcd.cpp
     src/outlier/statistical_removal.cpp
     src/exploration/moment_of_inertia.cpp
     src/registration/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp
     src/viewer/cloud_viewer.cpp
    )

set(incs 
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/cloud_viewer.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/filter.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/icp.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/icp_nl.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/io.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/moment_of_inertia_estimation.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/normal_3d.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/parse.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/pcd_io.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/pcl_visualizer.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/point_cloud.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/point_representation.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/point_types.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/print.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/statistical_outlier_removal.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/time.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/transforms.h
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/voxel_grid.h
    )

set(impl_incs 
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/thread.hpp
     include/pcl/${SYS_NAME}/make_shared.hpp
    )

add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${srcs} ${incs} ${impl_incs})

add_executable (${SYS_NAME} project_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (project_test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

In the CMakeLists, the source files are same with them in tutorials on pcl website. **But I don't know how to use them in project_test.cpp (=main.cpp).** **Should I make another hear files for the source files?** If then, How can I link or build them with which command in CMake?

I'm new with CMAKE, Visual Studio, PCL, so I want to know the guidance website or materials of them..

Sorry for my English and confusing words.

Comment: What do you mean by "use them in the `project_test.cpp`" when talk about *source files*? Do you want to use **functions**, defined in these files? If so, then declare these function in a (new) header, and include that header in the `project_test.cpp`.

Comment: Infinitely thank you.. I meant that I want to use functions in the other source files. I will try as your advice that declare a new header and include it.

Comment: I tried it. But these two errors came out.. Error 17 error C2352: 'cStatisticalRemoval::statistical_removal_main' : illegal call of non-static member function C:\Users\KWON\Desktop\PCL\PCLProjects\180530_ProjectTest\project_test.cpp 40 1 project_test    //////////////      18 IntelliSense: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object c:\Users\KWON\Desktop\PCL\PCLProjects\180530_ProjectTest\project_test.cpp 40 2 project_test

Comment: We cannot help you with that errors without viewing the code. Preferably, in form of [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your advice! This question was my first one.. so I didn't know that kind of rules.. I will keep that it mind when second questioning time..!!